# Why does NullPointerException appear for a class implementing PairFlatMapFunction?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-spark

I'm running a Spark application on yarn(spark-1.5.1 - hadoop2.6), and I get a NullPointerException when running on the cluster. I have searched some information for this problem, and I think my program doesn't seem to use a RDD function inside another RDD function.

I use the flatmaptopair function after using groupbykey function. And my overwrite Java code is like:

```
public class MyClass implements PairFlatMapFunction<Tuple2<A, Iterable<B>>, C, D> {

    private static OtherClass otherObj;

    public MyClass() {
        this.otherObj = new OtherClass();
    }

    @Override public Iterable<Tuple2<C, D>> call(Tuple2<A, Iterable<B>> tuple2) {

        otherObj.getInfo(); // NullPointerException

        // ... 

        return XX;
    }
}
```

However, the statement in my overload function threw a NullPointerException:

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 7.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 17, 4-52): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Did I make some mistakes in initialization of the static variable in Spark? or my understanding of RDD operations is wrong?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Thanks a lot! After searching more information about Java serialization,  I have realized that the variable which modifying `static` or `transient` wouldn't be serialized for transport. And the constructor won't be called after deserializing. So the `otherObj` in Workers should be undefine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `private static OtherClass otherObj` is `static` and as described in [1.5 Defining Serializable Fields for a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#a6250) of [Java Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html):

> Default serializable fields of a class are defined to be the non-transient and non-static fields.

...and the constructor won't be called after deserialization that leads to the NPE.

Java Serialization is the default serialization mechanism used to send a task from a driver to executors over the wire.

You can override the default behaviour using `writeObject` and `readObject` methods as described in [1.10 The Serializable Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#a4539).